# curl command cannot get contents from api.github, but the network is fine

Tags: php, laravel, curl, composer-php

I was trying use command `composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel`, to create a new laravel project.

But I got this in the terminal:

```
Failed to download jakub-onderka/php-console-color from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/JakubOnderka/PHP-Console-Color/zipball/e0b393dacf7703fc36a4efc3df1435485197e6c1" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
    Now trying to download from source
```

Then, I tried this command:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/JakubOnderka/PHP-Console-Color/zipball/e0b393dacf7703fc36a4efc3df1435485197e6c1
```

It cannot work.

However, when I entered the address in the browser(FireFox), It works!

What's wrong with that? Have suffered from this couple of days.

Comment: actually I got this error first:`Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/7bddbdc2a1f8d9c23205707e74455d74684e3031" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
    Now trying to download from source`

Comment: possible duplicate of [network is fine, but cannot create laravel project and show error in the command](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728079/network-is-fine-but-cannot-create-laravel-project-and-show-error-in-the-command)

Comment: Why are you asking exactly the same question 2 times??