# network is fine, but cannot create laravel project and show error in the command

Tags: php, laravel, curl, composer-php, homestead

I used this command to create a new laravel project in the homestead:

```
composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel
```

Then, the terminal show this error:

> Failed to download laravel/laravel from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/7bddbdc2a1f8d9c23205707e74455d74684e3031" file could not be downloaded: failed to open stream: Connection timed out
>           Now trying to download from source

I used curl command to get the content, failed again:

```
curl https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/7bddbdc2a1f8d9c23205707e74455d74684e3031
```

However, when I enter the address in the broswer(Firefox), it work! I can download the file by the browser!

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [curl command cannot get contents from api.github, but the network is fine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30727753/curl-command-cannot-get-contents-from-api-github-but-the-network-is-fine)

Comment: Why are you asking exactly the same question 2 times??

Answer (score 0):

This is probably the common issue about the reliability of the github downloads. It fails regularly.

A workaround is to increase `COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT` (defaults to 300) and force installing from source with the `--prefer-source` option:

```
COMPOSER_PROCESS_TIMEOUT=2000

composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel --prefer-source
```

Comment: stoped at command: `Executing command (CWD): git clone --no-checkout 'git://github.com/laravel/laravel.git' 'blog/' && cd 'blog/' && git remote add composer 'git://github.com/laravel/laravel.git' && git fetch composer`

Comment: @cirCavalier can you please try to replace `--prefer-source` with `--prefer-dist` and try again: `composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel --prefer-dist`

Comment: sir, I enter this command `composer create-project laravel/laravel Laravel --prefer-dist -vvv` it shows json files from packagist.org written successfully, but failed downloading from api.github.com, there is the full report: `Downloading https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/7bddbdc2a1f8d9c23205707e74455d74684e3031
    Downloading: 100%         
    Download failed, retrying...`

Comment: just updated my answer, I think it should work now :)

Comment: all right, i will try this during my dinner. But, still one question, I have try to enter https://api.github.com/repos/laravel/laravel/zipball/7bddbdc2a1f8d9c23205707e744‌​55d74684e3031 in my browser, it can download the file very fast, does this really github's reliability question?