# Downloading Laravel Admin Requires Me Git Credentials However It Is a Public Repo

Tags: laravel, git, github, ssh, composer-php

I'm using Laravel 8 and I wanted to download and install [Laravel-Admin](https://laravel-admin.org/docs/en/) but I faced this error on IDE Terminal:

```
Cloning failed using an ssh key for authentication, enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos
Head to https://github.com/settings/tokens/new?scopes=repo&description=Composer+on+ITnanoclub+2022-10-23+1036
to retrieve a token. It will be stored in "C:/Users/User 1/AppData/Roaming/Composer/auth.json" for future use by Composer.
Token (hidden):
```

I tried connecting with VPN but again showed me this error...

So what's going wrong here? How can I solve this issue?

I would really appreciate if you share any idea or suggestion about this with me please...

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Here is ping result:

[image]

Comment: Why are you trying to clone laravel-admin? Shouldn't you be using `composer require encore/laravel-admin` in your Laravel project as the website suggests?

Comment: @apokryfos Yes I just did `composer require encore/laravel-admin` not cloning. Srry

Answer (score 1):

It is a public repository, but  if your command tries a clone through SSH first, it might fall back to HTTPS and ask for credentials as part of its fallback mechanism.

That would be different if it tries immediately to clone with HTTPS: since it is a public repository, it would not require HTTPS credentials.

For that, try and set:

```
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf ssh://git@github.com/
git config --global url."https://github.com/".insteadOf git@github.com:
```

Then try again your `composer require encore/laravel-admin`

Comment: I tried those two commands but again showed me git credentials. I just updated the question and added a screenshot of it

Comment: @japose7523 Your screenshot does not ask for HTTPS credentials though.

Comment: It says **enter your GitHub credentials to access private repos**

Comment: And if I skip it by pressing Enter, it will show again a few moments later

Comment: @japose7523 Can you ping api.github.com? Is it a [DNS issue](https://github.com/composer/composer/issues/9376#issuecomment-718921358)?

Comment: I just added a picture of my ping results

Comment: I guess this is because of the our fking government blocked OpenSSL protocol in most ISPs

Comment: @japose7523 possible. Try and increase the timeout first, [as in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30728208/6309).